# Google Form, geocode and language

Tags: javascript, google-forms, geocode

First to say I'm not a programmer, I'm just following the steps in a tutorial until an error has occurred.
I have a form in google form where people enter their address in the format "city, state, country." Then I have a code to get your latitude and longitude. The problem is that when I type an address other than English does not work. For example it does not work: "Madrid, Madrid, España", but if it works with "madrid, madrid, spain."
Is it possible to work at least in English and Spanish?

Thank you very much, and here I leave part of the code that I copied from the tutorial:

```
/**
* Read values coming from the form
*/
function onFormSubmission(e) {
Logger.log("data!");
/**
 * Use Google services to get coordinates from a locality string
 */
 //Georeference the submission
 var loc = geocode(e.namedValues.location);

}

/**
 * Geocode using Google's services
 */
function geocode(address) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+escape(address)+"&sensor=false");
  var respObj=Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());

  var loc = {lat:NaN,lng:NaN};
  try {
    loc = respObj.results[0].geometry.location
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log("Error geocoding: "+address);
  }
 return loc;
}
```